# PHP Database Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Hi I'm very new to PHP because I just started learning this 2 days ago!
I'm trying to display my second table properly in my index.html file but I get this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  Take a look [image]

Any help would be much appreciated

Class

```
public class Category {
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    }
public class Product{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public int CategoryId{get;set;}
    public String Brand {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Price{get;set;
}
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                </p>

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>CategoryId</th>
                          <th>Brand</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Barcode</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php
                       include_once 'database.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id DESC';
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['category_id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['brand'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['barcode'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['price'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=250>';
                                echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }

                      ?>
                      </tbody>
                </table>

              <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
              <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <p>
              <a href="createCategory.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
              </p>
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>CategoryId</th>
                <th>Category Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            include_once 'database.php';
            <?php
            $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id DESC';
            foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row) {
                 echo '<tr>';
                 echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td width=250>';
                 echo '<a class="btn" href="readCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                 echo '&nbsp;';
                 echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                 echo '&nbsp;';
                 echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                 echo '</td>';
                 echo '</tr>';
             }
             Database::disconnect();
            ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you have a category table and its in the same db

Comment: Might have something to do with how that class is defined maybe static objects are not reusable or something along those lines.

Comment: If you look here http://imgur.com/3Km7f7m ! I have a table of category. If you check above the class is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second:

```
include 'database.php';
```

or use:

```
include_once 'database.php';
```

to prevent double loading of your database file.

You might want to consider not disconnecting and connecting again

Comment: It displayed my tables but my tables look funny! I'm trying to query my second table like I did in this first but it just displays the code.

Comment: You should start your php code by adding:  <?php in front of $sql2
(I think you removed 1 line too many)

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry to bother you again but do you know what I'm doing wrong for my querying " foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {" I'm getting the error in the image above.

Comment: Are you sure the category table exists in de database you connected with in database.php?

Comment: You could also try to add:
$pdo = Database::disconnect(); 
$pdo = Database::connect(); 
before the line starting with $sql2=

Comment: If I do the two lines of code you suggested, it crashes everything. I'm pretty sure I created a table category. Here are the files : https://mega.nz/#!qsMlkTYC!4fRF0_Gw6DeD332oW7vkQ-wTdEWuFqVViUsrIYxwwHY and this is myphpadmin database : http://imgur.com/3Km7f7m

Answer (score 1):

You have 6 `th` elements in the header and 7 `td` elements in your rows. Try to add a `th` in the header row.

Comment: Thanks I have fixed it now i have this error (Look at image) in this line " foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {" . I did the same thing I did with table one but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: First, check your query. Do you have a table of category? Do you have an id column for it? Then, test the query directly on your database server. If it works as expected, then check your $pdo variable using var_dump. If that's ok as well, then check the result of $pdo->query($sql2) using var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

This implies that the SQL query is failing (PDO returns false if the query fails).  The [manpage](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) says

> If you do not fetch all of the data in a result set before issuing your next call to PDO::query(), your call may fail. Call PDOStatement::closeCursor() to release the database resources associated with the PDOStatement object before issuing your next call to PDO::query().

**Edit:**
Doesn't look like this is the issue - try adding

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true).'</pre>';
```

after the for each loop, this should output the PDO error details.

Comment: It worked for my first table. I don't understand what it doesn't work for a shorter table.