# PHP Querying table Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I'm very new to PHP and I'm trying display a table like I did for PHP CRUD Grid(Look at image) but for some reason the foreach statement in index.php that I duplicated doesn't work. I get an error looking like this [

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Line 79 
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc5En.png)

I've also created a table using the following code

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
`category_category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`category_name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO `category` (`category_category_id`, `category_name`) VALUES
(1,'Drinks')
```

My data base looks like this on PHPmyadmin
[image]

This is the code that I used for the first grid:

```
                   include_once 'database.php';
                   $pdo = Database::connect();
                   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id DESC';
                   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['category_id'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['brand'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>'. $row['barcode'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>'. $row['price'] . '</td>';
```

and this is the code with the error that I'm trying to duplicate for the second grid

```
     $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                </p>

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>CategoryId</th>
                          <th>Brand</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Barcode</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php
                       include_once 'database.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id DESC';
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['category_id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['brand'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['barcode'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['price'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=250>';
                                echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }

                      ?>
                      </tbody>
                </table>

              <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
              <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <p>
              <a href="createCategory.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
              </p>
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>CategoryId</th>
                <th>Category Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>


            <?php
            include_once 'database.php';
            $pdo = Database::disconnect();
             $pdo = Database::connect();
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id DESC';
            foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                 echo '<tr>';
                 echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td width=250>';
                 echo '<a class="btn" href="readCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                 echo '&nbsp;';
                 echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                 echo '&nbsp;';
                 echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                 echo '</td>';
                 echo '</tr>';

             }
             Database::disconnect();
            ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
      <!--              <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                    </p>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>CategoryId</th>
                      <th>Catengory Name</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id DESC';
                  foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row) {
                       echo '<tr>';
                       echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                       echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';

                       echo '<td width=250>';
                       echo '<a class="btn" href="readCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                       echo '&nbsp;';
                       echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                       echo '&nbsp;';
                       echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                       echo '</td>';
                       echo '</tr>';
                     </div>
                   }
                   Database::disconnect();
                  ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table> -->
```

Comment: What is the problem? This is a ton of code and an illegible screenshot that I can't make any sense of. Can you describe the problem in more specific terms?

Comment: If you look in the image in the first one it shows an error which is   Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Line 79

Comment: The images are microscopic. When dealing with error messages, please post them as plain text. This not only improves readability, it means they can be searched for by other people.

Comment: and line 79 is what exactly?

Comment: `ORDER BY id` you don't have an `id` column. You have `category_category_id`. *There you have it folks*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820857/error-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: Next time, proper error handling would have told you so http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - Oh, and I didn't see the answers below when I wrote my comments.

Comment: Better check if `$pdo->query($sql)` outputs an array before feeding it to foreach.

Comment: You posted this not once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496859/php-database-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach but twice already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500927/php-database-table-query and all with the same syntax error. Again; had you been using proper error handling http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php you would have saved yourself a lot of time and trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to order by "id" when it's actually "category_category_id" in your db table. Change all references from id to category_category_id in the code in your loop too.

Comment: Yes thanks for the feedback It works now

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you don't have an id field in table category ? You have **category_category_id**

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
`category_category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`category_name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

So...

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_category_id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['category_category_id'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: Doesn't that make category_category_id the id ?

Comment: But it's not called "id"... The name matters !

Comment: Oh so I have to make `category_category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY  into `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY! I'll try it right away

Comment: No, you can use the code I gave you. Replace id by category_category_id

Comment: Yes thank you ! Finally it worked after trying to fix it for hours!

Comment: Great ! Good luck for next part then !

Comment: [Hint...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509529/php-querying-table-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach#comment54802812_33509529)